# My AJAX is not working, and giving no error (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

This is my first post here, I really need your help! Thanks in advance.

**Javascript file as below**

I create an AJAX request and send data to url `\getCount`.

But it seems nothing affect to my code and I see no errors in console.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

function  getCount(name,price,qty,type) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/getCount',
        data: {
            name: name,
            price: price,
            qty: qty,
            type: type
        },
        success:function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
        }
    });
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/getCount','ajaxController@index');
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request){
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.']);
}
```

Comment: check the network tab in your browser dev tools see what's happening if you don't see any console messages.

Comment: your ajax is incomplete. how you are going to map the data in ajax. Use jQuery to first get the data by `.val()` method then send it through ajax to backend.

Comment: What is your ultimate Url ?

Comment: How are you initiating your `getCount()` Javascript function?  As suggested, check your browser's devtools - look at the network tab to see if the AJAX request really happened.  Check the console, maybe there are some errors that prevented anything from happening.